# select the last article inside of a section if it is odd

Tags: html, css, selector

Is it possible to select the last article inside this section if it is odd?

```
<section>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
</section>
```

Im trying to do this with the :nth-last-of-type selector

Comment: what effort have you made? it is possible.

Comment: and what do you mean by odd?

Comment: have u seen the :last-child selector?

Answer (score 2):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nU9gK/)

You can simply use the CSS, e.g:

```
article:last-child:nth-child(odd){
    color:red;
}
```